# Cannot connect to SQL Server Integration Services from SQL Server Management Studio: "Class Not Registered"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis, sql-server-2014

On a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, I have installed MS SQL Server 2014, using a very typical installation. On a Windows 7 client, I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2016. I am able to connect to my SQL Server (as a Database Engine) just fine using SSMS. However, when I try to use SSMS to connect to Integration Services on the *exact same* server host, like so:

[image: Connect to Integration Services with SSMS]

I get this error:

[image: Class not registered Error]

I do not believe I have SQL Server 2005 Integration Services installed since I did an out-of-the-box SQL Server 2014 installation, and I would expect (hope, at least) that the Integration Services matched.

However, I am able to deploy SSIS packages just fine and run them using SSMS from the Integration Services Catalog. I only run into issues when trying to log in directly to Integration Services or access the SSIS Package Store.

The version of SQL Server is 12.0.4459.0 (this is also the version of my Integration Services service, MsDtsSrvr.exe).

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try downloading and using SSMS 2014 to see if you can connect? This problem used to come up when using different versions of SSIS and SSMS.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered that as a problem! I just installed SSMS 2014 instead of SSMS 2016, and ... now I get a different error (RPC Server is not available), but that gives me a new lead to follow! If I can get that figured out, then your suggestion will be the correct answer.

Comment: Are you able to connect if you turn the firewall off on SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am. Brilliant! You can post this as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it, otherwise I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try downloading and using SSMS 2014 to see if you can connect? This problem used to come up when using different versions of SSIS and SSMS.

Comment: Yes, the SSMS version has to be the same as the Integration Services in order to connect to Integration Services. See a response from MSFT here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2779968/ssms-2016-error-connecting-to-integration-services-on-a-sql-server-2008-r2-instance